# Dataclass as config store: Importing instanciated dataclass to another file to use as global config class

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, python-dataclasses

I just came from mount stupid and am now residing in the valley of despair. Please help me out. I want to use a dataclass to globaly store the config of my scripts/programm.

I have 3 main conceptual problems currently:

a) I used to use a dot `.env` file and simply created the dataclass like this:

```
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

@dataclass
class MyParams:
    val_a: str = os.environ['VALUE_A']
    val_b: str = os.environ['VALUE_B']
```

Then i could simply do `from xyz import MyParams` to all my scripts and it would have the same instance variables/values everywhere after i created an instance of it like `myparams_instance = MyParams()` in each individual script. Is this good practice? Can i somehow only create one isntance of this dataclass and have it globally available?

b) I would want to use a yaml file instead. How do i create only a single instance of a dataclass preferably in the script were the dataclass is defined such that i can later use in multiple scripts? Specifically i would want to load the values of the `MyParams` class form a `config.yaml` file?
I tried this... and it works but it just feels very wrong?

```
@dataclass
class MyParams:
    val_a: str
    val_b: str
    ....

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = MyParams.read_yaml()
        self.val_a = self.config['LEVEL_XYZ']['VALUE_A']
        self.val_b = self.config['LEVEN_XYZ']['VALUE_A']
        ....

    @staticmethod
    def read_yaml(config_path: str = "config.yaml"):
        with open(config_path) as yaml_file:
            try:
                return yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
            except yaml.YAMLError as e:
                logger.error(f"ERROR When reading params from config.yaml: {e}")
```

c) ... How is something like this done "professinonally"? I do know about Hydra and Pydantic but would like to understand a more simple saelfmade solution first. And especially understand what is best practice. But google leaves me with more questionmarks than i would like to admit.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I thought a lot about similar questions recently. And tried my luck here too. But I didn't get much of a response too. In the end I liked the way how mlflow does it for environment variables.